# load mat file unicode depending on big or little endian

Tags: endianness

I am trying to convert a matlab structure from a .mat file to a python dict. I use scipy.io module to do this. 
actually I have some trouble. for the same data containing in the mat file, the loadmat function return an unicode that depends on how the mat file is generated (windows OS or Linux/Inux OS)
I think that it is question of big or little endian (I am not sure)

can you help me please